# record mouse movements on desktop (not form) in windows application form

Tags: c#, winforms, onmousemove

I have created a windows application form, it can display the opening window that user opens in real time. And I need to record the mouse movement. However, I could only record the mouse movement on windows form by using Cursor. Is there any way in C# can record the movements on desktop NOT form?

I think there may be 2 ways, but have not found the solutions yet:

1. find a way to record the mouse movement on the whole screen, so that when users open any kind of window, their mouse movements can be recorded
2. I'm using handle for foregroundwindow to display the info the opening window, is there any way to use handle to record the mouse movements?

Many many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

Comment: What's the motivation for this? You could use a global hook, but I don't really recommend it. Depending on why you need this information and what you plan on doing with it, there might be better alternatives. For example, capturing the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need global Windows hooks. There is a really good tutorial: http://web.archive.org/web/20130912133933/http://www.jarloo.com/recording-keystrokes-and-the-mouse-and-play-them-back-in-c/

Comment: Dead link, any replacements?

Comment: heres the related blog post http://www.dylansweb.com/2014/10/low-level-global-keyboard-hook-sink-in-c-net/

Comment: @TJWolschon great link!